# peculiar issue with powershell enabling Antimalware service for cloud services

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I was going through documentation for enabling antimalware service for cloud services. here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn771718.aspx.

When i execute the below power shell in my local machine, it work perfectly.

`[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $XmlConfig = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument 
$XmlConfig.load('..\Antimalware.xml')
Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension -ServiceName TestingPowerShell -AntimalwareConfiguration $XmlConfig`

When i move this code to Cloud Services and invoke above powershell script has a start up task, i.e through batch command, Antimalware service is not enabled.

When i remote desktop to cloud service, I'm surprised to see Azure tool SDK is not present/installed. I found log, where it says .NET framework 2.0 is required when running powershell 2.0,  but when i check cloud service's powershell version is already 4.0. I could not understand how to invoke this anti-malware service has start-up task.

Comment: looks like i cannot have power shell has startup task for cloud service, need to have manual script to enable antimalware

Comment: Do you have a reference that states we cant run a powershell script in a startup task? I thought I would need a startup task to enable azure antimalware for every new staging deployment.